# Any Ideas on Rendering HTML to an Image or Screenshot to Image on Phonegap Build?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, cordova, screenshot, phonegap-build

I've been doing some research and I came across this little number: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/10/webpage-screenshot-with-html5-js/ that allows you to turn HTML into a blob (essentially as a screenshot)... HTML2Canvas does this, too, but not quite as well: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

However the problem is that's where I'm stuck. I'd ideally like to render HTML to an image (either as a blob or a local file) and upload it to Facebook via the Graph API.

My problems start with < 3.0 Android browsers not being able to accommodate blobs. Has anyone come up with a solution that would work on Phonegap Build that would allow me to do this?  Since I'm on Build I'm probably limited to Javascript, HTML5, and whatever Android / Safari allows.

Comment: The first link just wraps the html into a `Blob`, html2canvas renders the DOM into a canvas which can be for example exported into a png.

Comment: Very true, however, html2canvas is very limited in what it can render.  I have a very simple histogram made from DIVs and html2canvas cannot render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is old, but maybe the answer will help someone.

You can use the [screenshot plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1055) for iOS and Android.
For details, read the [Documentation on Github](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot/blob/8705f89/README.md)